# Installing a Plugin in Phonegap (NFC)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm pretty new on phonegap, I'm trying to install the nfc plugin without any success for now.
I think this could apply to whatever plugin.

I'm trying to install it manually, since the plugman isnt working for me.
I've tried different ways but nothing.

What I have now is:

Config.xml with this string added:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin"/>
```

The index.html with those scripts correctly placed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap-nfc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

The file in the plugins directory named:

```
com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin
```

The scr folder placed in the root of the project with this structure

```
/src/com/chariotsolutions/nfc/plugin/
```

With 2 files inside: NfcPlugin.java and Util.java

The error i receive is always:

```
Failed to initialize the NfcPlugin Class not found
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem you need to report to plugin owner.

https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/new